# How to properly catch unload events from an iFrame

Tags: javascript

I am trying to catch an unload or beforeunload event from inside an iFrame. It works fine except in Chrome the event is not fired when I click the reload button.

What is a cross-browser solution to this that always works?

Comment: Please clarify ... by reload you mean reloading the main page? is the event handler inside the iframe or in the main page? Does this work in other browsers? which ones does it work with? Are the main page and iframe in the same domain? Show at least a minimal example of the code you are attempting to write

Comment: I'm reloading the parent page and listening to the unload in the iframe. It works in firefox. Currently I'm looking at the iframes on the same domain, but I'm going to be looking at cross domain next.